# ToolStripDropDownButton, how to remove all DropDownItems?

Tags: c#, forms, drop-down-menu, toolstripdropdown

How to remove all DropDownItems from a ToolStripDropDownButton, if its propery is read only?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the Clear method:

```
toolStripDropDownButton1.DropDownItems.Clear();
```

Answer (score 1):

The DropDownItems property is a collection. See

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.toolstripitemcollection.aspx

Therefore, you can use Remove and RemoveAt to remove items, preferably using a for loop.

In addition, the property is read only in a sense that you can't set it using an operator, but you can modify the contents of the collection.